Assisted Reproductive Technology or Masturbatorium
Looking for a movie where there's this couple who I infer has difficulty conceiving naturally so they go for artificial means.
They go to some place called a masturbatorium or something to that effect wherein there's this guy led there by a nurse who tells shows him to a TV, remote and three piles of magazines:
men with women
women with women
miscellaneous
She then presents him with a cup which I infer is to be filled with semen.
Later on, the nurse tells his wife something like "Hes's been in there for over twenty minutes."
The wife replies "That's not too long for him."
I suspect this was an American film sometime from 1990-2009

The 'trip to the sperm donation/analysis clinic' is almost a rom-com film trope. I'd bet there's a dozen films that might fit into this description.

@DA. Edited....

It's A Smile Like Yours (1997) and this is the sperm sample scene: 



